# Сборка приложений в Xcode 9 beta, созданных в старых версиях Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Есть приложение, давно работающее и выложенное в AppStore, его deployment target - iOS 7.0, работает стабильно до iOS 10.3. В Xcode 8.3.3 оно открывается, собирается и запускается. Есть задача - запустить его на iOS 11.0. Собирать под iOS 11.0 умеет пока только Xcode 9 beta, а так же только он содержит симуляторы с iOS 11.0.

**Вариант 1 в лоб**: скачать XCode 9 beta. **НО** бета-версии XCode 9 с 4 по 6 при запуске проекта выдают фатальную ошибку и крашится.

**Вариант 2**: собрать проект через утилиту командной строки для XCode 9 beta. **НО** сборка (проект использует кстати Cocoapods) оканчивается ошибкой:

> ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

В попытках исправить было найдено много решений, но для старых версий XCode, а именно:

1. Обновить Cocoapods;
2. Удалить все pods и установить заново;
3. В поле
   проекта Other Linker Flags: 
           a) удалить все флаги; 
           b) удалить все флаги, оставив только $(inherited);
4. Избавиться от usе_frameworks в podfile;
5. На вкладке Build Phrases добавить нужные библиотеки в Link Binary With Libraries;

Все это не возымело действия.

**Вариант 3**: создать проект заново в XCode 9 и вручную добавить туда исходники и зависимости. Результат такой же как и в предыдущем пункте.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Какие еще способы адаптировать приложение под iOS 11.0?

Comment: обновили все pods тоже? включая Alamofire?

Comment: все pods обновлены, Alamofire не использовалась

Comment: AFNetworking я имел ввиду, что то же самое для ObjC

Answer (score 1):

Есть маленький нюанс с Xcode 9 и iOS 11. Там больше не собирается 32 битный код. Как результат если у вас в проекте были либы, уже собранные под 32 бита или сборка которых предполагалась в 32 битном варианте, то можете с ними попрощаться. Что делать? Адаптировать проект под 64 разряда.

Судя по ошибке линкер не находит AFNetworking. Вообще AFNetworking собирается под 64 разряда. В частности убедитесь что AFNetworking собирается успешно в Pos сабпроекте. Как вариант рассмотрите отказ от CocoaPod и используйте Carthage. Но скорее всего проблема в том что AFNetworking не собралась либо у вас не верно прописаны зависимости (Target dependencies) и сборка проекта начинается до сборки либы.